# Задача на умножение матриц с использованием NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Всем привет, изучаю возможности NumPy. Не пойму, правда, тут моя математика просела окончательно или понимание Python.

Введите через пробел 16 чисел, создайте из них вектор. Преобразуйте вектор в матрицу А размера 4 на 4 любым способом. Найдите натуральное число x из диапазона [1, 9], для которого матрица вида

x 0 0 0

0 x 0 0

0 0 x 0

0 0 0 x

при умножении на матрицу A увеличит всё её элементы в 3 раза. Выведите на экран произведение матриц.

Мое начало кода:

```
import numpy as np

data=input('Enter 16 numbers using space: ')
lst=list(map(int, data.split(' ')))

a=np.array(lst).reshape(4,4)
b=a*3
```

Дальше думала сделать что-то вроде деления матриц, но запуталась + в ответе матрица далеко не диагональная получается:

```
from numpy.linalg import inv
b_inv=inv(b)

c=a*b_inv
print(c)
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значение *x* отыскивается в уме и не зависит от другой матрицы. Оператор `*` в `NumPy` означает поэлементное умножение массивов. Вам нужен оператор `@`.

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array(range(16)).reshape(4, 4)
print(a)

b = 3 * np.eye(4)
print(b)

c = a @ b
print(c)
```

> ```
> $ python matrices.py
> [[ 0  1  2  3]
>  [ 4  5  6  7]
>  [ 8  9 10 11]
>  [12 13 14 15]]
> [[3. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 3. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 3. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 3.]]
> [[ 0.  3.  6.  9.]
>  [12. 15. 18. 21.]
>  [24. 27. 30. 33.]
>  [36. 39. 42. 45.]]
> ```